# Java Applet Debugger/Watcher Suggestion

Tags: java, applet

I have a Java applet that runs on visiting a site, whereupon it receives, parses and displays streamed data. Unfortunately said applet isn't particularly well designed and I would like to extract the streamed data to make it more useful for myself.

In order to do this, I need to get insight into the connections made, data being exchanged, the state of variables in use and so on, so that I can replicate the log in and streaming.

So far I've been using Wireshark for network traffic, Java Debug Console and eyeballing the applet source installed on my system but still without success- primarily because there is a series of connections being made to the remote server and I am unsure the exact nature of the requests (and responses) and the variables contained.

Does a suitable app exist that can provide such insight?

I should add that I have no experience developing with Java, my knowledge is in Python, mainly.